# Time /space complexity for checking whether array is an permutation?

Tags: java

I was trying to write an algo for the below problem:

https://app.codility.com/programmers/lessons/4-counting_elements/perm_check/

The problem require me to solve it in

```
**Complexity**:

expected worst-case time complexity is O(N);
expected worst-case space complexity is O(N), beyond input storage (not counting the storage required for input arguments).
```

Could somebody explain to me whether my solution fits the requirements:

```
public static int checkPermutation(int arr[]) {
        int size = arr.length ;
        Set<Integer> s = new HashSet<>();   
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            s.add(arr[i]);
        }   

        for (int i = 1; i <= size; i++) {
            boolean check = s.remove(i);
            if(!check){
                return 0;
            }
        }
        return 1;
}
```

Please explain. Since I am iterating from 1 to size 2 times, does it pass o(N) time complexity requirement?

Comment: O(2*N) is O(N), so it is O(N)

Comment: One point to note is add operation on a HashSet is amortized O(1)

Comment: amortized or not: you don't need any hash maps here. Think simpler. *Much* simpler. You need one single array of booleans, that's it. If you can mutate the input array, you don't need even that, you need only one or two extra integer variables and no extra data structures at all.

Comment: Your algorithm, and its implementation break if the arrays contain repeated values. You need a hashtable that counts the elements.

Comment: Give me the sample array where it  breaks.

Comment: I would agree with @Andrey Tyukin. Note that lesson name is `counting_elements`, your task is to learn `pigeons and holes` priniciple. So don't waste time and resources on hash maps.  boolean or bit array makes the work simpler and faster, it guarantees O(N).

Answer (score -3):

You are doing 2 linear time and linear space (O(N)) loops here. This brings your time and space complexity 2 * n or O(2n). We don't care about the 2 here because as we approach infinity its negligible. This means your time complexity is O(N), your space complexity is also O(N)

Comment: Not sure how you think this answer applies to the question above. Did you mean to post it to a totally different question instead, or did you just fail to read this question before answering?